# PHP: using a method that may or may not have parameters

Tags: php, methods

I have a function in a class that queries a database. I create the query on the fly by using where clauses based on variables.

Say I have a method like this:

```
function getBackups($from, $to, $clientid){

    //sql here
    //add where clause if $from and $to not null...

}
```

If I want to call this somewhere In a situation where I have no from or to variables I would simply put $backups->getBackups() but I'd get an error about a missing parameter.

If I do this:

```
function getBackups($from = null, $to = null, $clientid = null){

    //sql here
    //add where clause if $from and $to not null...
}
```

Will this be the solution? or will it be more like this if I'm not passing parameters?

```
$backups->getBackups($from = null, $to = null, clientid = null)
```

Hope this makes sense,

Jonesy

Comment: Your solution by providing default values is okay.

Comment: The first. However, be mindful of the order of your parameters, as it will matter. And if you want to ONLY put in one of the parameters one time, say, the $to variable, you'll need to write $backups->getBackups(null,'the to'); because the order matters

Comment: thanks DampeS8N for that info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do what you say:

```
function getBackups($from = null, $to = null, $clientid = null){

    //sql here
    //add where clause if $from and $to not null...
}
```

an then you can call it just like:

```
$backups->getBackups()
```

or you can call

```
$backups->getBackups($from, $to, $clientid)
```

Inside the function you can check if the aprameters are null (or any other default value you like to use) and execute the code depending of the parameters.

HTH regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getBackups($from = null, $to = null, $clientid = null){

    //sql here
    //add where clause if $from and $to not null...
}
```

Is the solution for functions with optional parameters, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

optional parameters in php is as simple as this:

```
function getBackups($from = null, $to = null, $clientid = null){

    //sql here
    //add where clause if $from and $to not null...
}
```

And to call it, you just call:

```
backups->getBackups();
```

or

```
backups->getBackups("from");
```

if you include any arguments to the function, they will replace the default values in the order they appear.